# Authorize using acess token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have secured my application using oauth2 standard flow with amazon cognito. It works fine.

Sometimes i want to link to my webapp through my mobile app, and i dont want the user to sign in again. How do i create an @AnonymousAllowed endpoint that takes in an access token, authenticates using spring security and redirects to the homepage of my application?

I've tried creating an endpoint that returns the jsessionid, then another anonymous endpoint that accepts a jsessionid, sets the cookie and redirects to the homepage, but it didnt work.

I've tried setting the authorization header to the access token. But i feel like that wont work properly because the token will expire after few minutes, and spring wont handle authorization for me, rather i have to do it "manually"

Comment: How is configured your Spring application? Provide with dependencies (with versions), properties and Java configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help in your situation. But you can check if anything you can refer from below. It's a custom filter with custom token validator.

You can use Custom TokenAuthenticationFilter by extending **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter**

```
public class CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


@Autowired
private TokenValidatorService tokenValidatorService;

public CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter(final RequestMatcher requiresAuth) {
    super(requiresAuth);
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

    String token= httpServletRequest.getHeader(CommonConstants.OAUTH_HEADER_KEY_AUTHORIZATION);
   //Get the custom header
   //Validate token using custom validator based on header value
    Optional<OAuthResponseData> oauthResponseData = tokenValidatorService.validateAccessToken(token, provider);
     ...
    Authentication requestAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(oauthResponseData.get(), oauthResponseData.get().getOauthToken());
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(requestAuthentication);

}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain, final Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
 }    

}
```

In **TokenValidatorService** you can implement **OAuth2TokenValidator** to validate the token

**Spring Security config class:**

```
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

@Configuration  
public static class CustomTokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    
    @Autowired
    protected CustomTokenAuthenticationProvider customTokenAuthenticationProvider;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity.ignoring()
        ...
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS).authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .logout().disable();
            
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        // filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customTokenAuthenticationProvider);
    }
 }
}
```